# Codeigniter: repopulate dropdowns array using set_value

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, drop-down-menu, populate

I have this piece of code:

```
<?php for ( $i=1; $i<=9; $i++ ) : ?>
  <select name="codes[]">
    <?php foreach ( $errors as $error ) : ?>
    <option value="<?=$error->code?>" <?=set_select( 'codes', $error->code )?>><?=$error->fault?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

The set_select part doesn't seem to work well, even though I added the validation rule in my controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules( 'codes', '', '' );
```

After submitting the form, all dropdowns get the last dropdown's selected value.

Any idea how I could fix this? The user guide doesn't give details about this specific situation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry exhausted, I didn't see you set the rule, try giving it a real rule and see if that works. Since it will always have a value this should work fine.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('codes','codes','trim|required');
```

Comment: Hi, Rick. Thanks, but it still doesn't work. I added the square brackets to field name in validation, as it was returning an error (string passed, array expected): $this->form_validation->set_rules( 'codes[]', 'codes', 'trim|required' );

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed the array and the incremented loop. Try running the validation inside a similar loop. It's trying to validate one control rather than all of them and it has nothing to return against. For example codes[1] is sending data and it's not being validated because it isn't matching a rule.